# Comparing two dates in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

In my elastic search index, I have a date field called "created" which in the following format,
{'created': '2021-03-09T13:56:16.639Z' }
But I need to get the documents which are created in specific date which is in format yyyy-mm-dd and I don't want the time to be compared.

I tried something like this but It not works,

```
    res = es.search(index='blogs',body={'query': {"match_all": {}}, "aggs": {
                    "range": {
                      "date_range": {
                        "field": "created",
                        "format": "YYYY-mm-dd",
                        "ranges": [
                          { "to": "2021-03-09" },
                          { "from": "2021-03-09" }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }})
print(res)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is wrong, it must be `yyyy-MM-dd`, change ti and it will work as expected

```
                  "date_range": {
                    "field": "created",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",             <--- change this
                    "ranges": [
                      { "to": "2021-03-09" },
                      { "from": "2021-03-09" }
                    ]
                  }
```